# Como fazer um inteiro armazenar um número de 12 dígitos?

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, tipagem

Eu preciso encontrar o maior fator primo do número 600851475143.

Por ser um número bem grande, não consigo armazená-lo em uma variável do tipo inteiro normal.

O código que fiz para encontrar o maior fator primo de um número é esse:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int maiorFator = 0;
    unsigned long int numero = 600851475143;

    for (int i = 2; numero != 1;) {
        if (numero % i == 0) {
            numero /= i;
            if (maiorFator < i) {
                maiorFator = i;
            }
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nMaior fator primo: " << maiorFator << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Eu já tentei usar os modificadores `long` e `unsigned` na variável `numero`, mas não funciona, sempre ocorre *overflow*, e por conta disso não consigo o resultado.

Não posso usar variáveis do tipo `float` nem `double`, pois eu uso o operador de resto `%` para fazer os cálculos.

O algoritmo de fatoração funciona bem, pelo menos para os números que testei. Meu único problema é não conseguir armazenar o número grande.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Vou responder apenas o que foi perguntado.

O tipo correto neste caso é o [`long long`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) que garante em especificação os 64 bits necessários para um número deste tamanho, outros tipos podem ter esse tamanho se o compilador quiser, mas não garante.

Dito isto, o algoritmo está errado mas acho que você vai querer consertar sozinho já que é um exercício.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

pode usar uma destas opções. a primeira se quiser uma variável que lhe armazene só inteiros a segunda se quiser algo mais global

```
long long; long double
```

pode também optar por criar uma classe com este tipo de variável prototipada, e adicioná-la a um repositório/biblioteca, da sua autoria

```
long long uVar(long long myUVar) {return myUVar;}
```

alternativamente

```
long double uVar(long long myUVar) {return myUVar;}
```

Answer (score -1):

uma possível abordagem, será a técnica de serialização, muito usada para gravar estados em motores gráficos de videojogos, sobretudo se tivermos em conta os primórdios, e que pode ser usada para fins de gpgpu

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

```
#include <fstream>

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// gps coordinate
//
// illustrates serialization for a simple type
//
class gps_position
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    // When the class Archive corresponds to an output archive, the
    // & operator is defined similar to <<.  Likewise, when the class Archive
    // is a type of input archive the & operator is defined similar to >>.
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & degrees;
        ar & minutes;
        ar & seconds;
    }
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;
public:
    gps_position(){};
    gps_position(int d, int m, float s) :
        degrees(d), minutes(m), seconds(s)
    {}
};

int main() {
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // create class instance
    const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

    // save data to archive
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << g;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    // ... some time later restore the class instance to its orginal state
    gps_position newg;
    {
        // create and open an archive for input
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        // read class state from archive
        ia >> newg;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```